# error in ansible 2.4 modules after upgrading ubuntu from 16 to 20

Tags: python, ansible, ubuntu-20.04

I upgraded from ubuntu-16 to ubuntu-20 after that I couldn't run ansible modules , my ansible version is 2.4
I tried to run this in ansible:

```
- name: "add repository to download PHP v 7.3"
  apt_repository: 
    repo: '{{ item }}'
    state: present
  with_items:
      - ppa:ondrej/php
```

but I got this error :

````
failed: (item=ppa:ondrej/php) => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "item": "ppa:ondrej/php", "module_stderr": "Shared connection to  closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_g7r3bmdr/ansible_module_apt_repository.py\", line 189, in __iter__\r\n    raise StopIteration\r\nStopIteration\r\n\r\nThe above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:\r\n\r\nTraceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_g7r3bmdr/ansible_module_apt_repository.py\", line 556, in <module>\r\n    main()\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_g7r3bmdr/ansible_module_apt_repository.py\", line 519, in main\r\n    sourceslist.add_source(repo)\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_g7r3bmdr/ansible_module_apt_repository.py\", line 439, in add_source\r\n    self._add_valid_source(source, comment, file)\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_g7r3bmdr/ansible_module_apt_repository.py\", line 352, in _add_valid_source\r\n    for filename, n, enabled, source, comment in self:\r\nRuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 0}```
````

Comment: put quotes around this `ppa:ondrej/php` make it `"ppa:ondrej/php"`

Comment: still the same issue

Comment: As [the upstream issue says](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/71987#issuecomment-700509464), ansible 2.4 is positively ancient, given that modern releases are 2.11 (or, v3 or v4 depending on how one looks at that)